# MVC 3 Razor with EF : Best tool for reverse engineering , decompiling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, reverse-engineering, decompiler

I have inherited, source-code missing, numerous light-weight web applications written for the MVC 3 Razor framework on top of EF.  I tried using a decompiler (Telerik's JustDecompile) on the app's dll, and got back a warm mess.  My question is, for those whom have done this before, did they find one of the other decompilers any more helpful than others (Redgate's Reflector, JetBrains, ?) and/or if anyone had recommendations for what has *got* to be a fairly common conundrum by now.

Also interested in hearing if anyone has found a particularly useful strategy to load up one of these decompilers with the necessary MVC and EF libraries, so it can "connect the dots", as it were.

NOTE: This is entirely different than reverse-engineering/decompiling your standard C# app or even ASP.NET, from what I have experienced. So please consider that before answering.

Much thanks, even for witnesses to our shared pain.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you mean by "this is entirely different than reverse-engineering/decompiling your standard C# app"?  It sounds like you are trying to get the source code which is exactly what reverse-engineering is.

Comment: In rough terms, using a decompiler on a C# assembly generally gives you something you can drop right into a project and execute.  I probably conflated the problems with decompiling the EF-related code with the MVC issues.  I do know that the reliance on templates (especially .tt files) is not something older ASP.NET apps had to contend with.

Comment: The operative word is STANDARD, which was a poor choice of word, perhaps instead of "simple" or "straightforward".  I am claiming MVC on EF is radically different than decompiling an assembly not heavily reliant on Frameworks.